Understanding やる vs. できる in "To finish"
I just randomly had this thought when I was reviewing the use of できる. One of the meanings is "to finish," but these two sound...similar.

宿題をやった。


宿題ができた。

Not going to pad this out with explanation: these sound exactly the same. I know the former has a nuance of "to do with effort," but is there any difference necessarily?


宿題をやった。
宿題ができた。

It's the latter that is associated with a nuance of "with effort". 宿題をやった plainly means "I did my homework". It says nothing about effort.
宿題ができた may just mean "My homework is complete", but it may also carry the meaning of "succeeded in" or "was able to do", depending on the context. For example, if you were given difficult homework but succeeded in solving it, then you'll probably say 宿題ができた.

You get a sticker.
